react native navigation for phased authorization
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootNavigationProps>();

const RootNavigation = () => {
  const {token, logout} = useAuth();
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const {width} = useWindowDimensions();
  const {auth_user_info, loading} = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.authUserInfoSlice,
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(authUserInfoRequest({token})).then((result: any) => {
      if (result.payload.message === 'Unauthenticated.') {
        logout();
      }
    });
  }, [dispatch, logout, token]);


  if (token?.token === undefined) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(' [RootNavigation.tsx:109]', token?.token);

      return (
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Login"
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
            animation: 'slide_from_right',
          }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Stack.Screen name="LoginOTP" component={LoginOTP} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    }, 500);
  }

  const authenticated =
    (token?.token &&
      auth_user_info?.create_account_status === '1' &&
      auth_user_info?.job_category_id === '3') ||
    (token?.token &&
      auth_user_info?.create_account_status === '1' &&
      auth_user_info?.add_car_status === '1');

  const hasTokenNotAuthenticated =
    token?.token &&
    auth_user_info?.add_car_status === '0' &&
    auth_user_info?.create_account_status === '0';

  const registeredButNotCar =
    token?.token &&
    auth_user_info?.add_car_status === '0' &&
    auth_user_info?.create_account_status === '1';

  if (hasTokenNotAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={'Register'}
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          animation: 'slide_from_right',
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ScannerHomeDriver" component={ScannerHomeDriver} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="CameraScreenDriver"
          component={CameraScreenDriver}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="DataDriverLicense" component={DataDriverLicense} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  } else if (registeredButNotCar) {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={'ScannerHomeTechnical'}
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          animation: 'slide_from_right',
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ScannerHomeTechnical"
          component={ScannerHomeTechnical}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="CameraScreenTechnical"
          component={CameraScreenTechnical}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="DataAuto" component={DataAuto} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
headerShown: false,
        animation: 'slide_from_right',
      }}>
      {authenticated && <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

It is necessary to check the status of the registration at the time of entry and according to it it will flash and should Error. Couldn't find any screens for the navigator. Have you defined any screens as its children? The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Register"} was not handled by any navigator. these problems do not exist
during the first login, the user registers a phone number and passes the OTP, after which he receives a token, at that time and when opening the program again, I have to go to the page to fill in data, and so I have 4 stages.
My problem is that I can go to the next page but not the previous one. I have to understand all that by means of values. We open the application again.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
